How to switch to a frame and work with multiple elements which are existed in the frame?
I have few elements which exists in different views. In one view, element is not in frame. In another view, element is in frame. I have written functions to work with the elements when not in frame. Now I want to customize the same functions to work with the elements both when in frame and not in frame.
If it is in Selenium, we can just switch to frame when the elements are in frame and all rest of the code is same.
Can someone please answer?
public async Task ClickCommand(string name, string subName = null, string subSecondName = null)
{
    var commandLocator = Locator(CommandBarLocators.CommandItem.Replace("[Name]", name));
    try
    {
        await ClickAsync(commandLocator, new LocatorClickOptions { Timeout = 7000 });
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        await ClickMoreCommandEllipsis();
        await ClickAsync(commandLocator);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subName))
    {
        var subNameLocator = Locator(CommandBarLocators.CommandItem.Replace("[Name]", subName));
        await ClickAsync(subNameLocator);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subSecondName))
    {
        var secondSubNameLocator = Locator(CommandBarLocators.CommandItem.Replace("[Name]", subSecondName));
        await ClickAsync(secondSubNameLocator);
    }

}```


You can add an IFrame argument to the function. Then pass the MainFrame or a ChildFrame.

I have many functions to handle those elements. I cannot add IFrame argument for each function. Do we have any other way? @hardkoded

Nope. You'll need to refactor them.

you can add as an optional parameter so no need to change much @NoNoNo
